# A clean way of 'if statement structure' to avoid java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: java, algorithm

I have the following code:

```
dist[i - 1][j] = i - 1 >= 0 ? findDist(matrix, i - 1, j, rowNum, colNum, dist) : 0;
```

And I got the  `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`

So I have to change the code to:

```
if (i - 1 >= 0) {
        dist[i - 1][j] =  findDist(matrix, i - 1, j, rowNum, colNum, dist);
}
```

However, it gets less cleaner. I am wondering is there a better way to structure the above code? Thanks!

Comment: That's arguably much cleaner. Less  lines != more clean. Ternarys should be used carefully.

Comment: `if (i > 0)` would be more concise, if that's your thing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Or even better `int index = i - 1;` and use that then. This also avoids using `i - 1` three times.

Comment: The ternary makes no sense anyway. What field would you give 0?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoid branching in this specific case, because you're doing an assignment, and the IOOBE is coming from the left-hand side of the assignment (e.g., the target). There's nothing you can do on the *right-*hand side of the assignment would would prevent evaluating the left-hand side and ultimately accessing an out-of-bounds index. You need to either assign to it, or skip over assigning to it. That's branching.

There are languages where that branching could be done differently, but in Java, your `if` is how you would do that.

You could hide the branch away in a utility function that accepted a lambda, but that would be probably be overkill for the given example.

Answer (score 0):

You get the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException in dist[i-1]. Since the i-1 can be equals to -1. So it is better if you could check whether the value is grater than or equal 0 before access the dist array elements.